# Oracle SUM calculated values

Tags: oracle, sum, subquery

I'm trying to figure out how I can or if it's possible to sum the returned values from columns on the fly to have a total value returned for each record instead of having to calculate it again.

The query has multiple sub-queries which all calculate correctly and return an integer value, I'm trying to find a way to add these values on the fly into a `Total` column, is it even possible!?

```
SELECT (SELECT value FROM ....) AS NUM_1
, (SELECT value FROM ....) AS NUM_2
, (SELECT value FROM ....) AS NUM_3
, SUM(NUM_1 + NUM_2 + NUM_3) AS TOTAL
FROM DUAL;
```

This is the output I'm looking to achieve:

```
NUM_1 | NUM_2 | NUM_3 | Total
=============================
3     | 4     | 3     | 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with numbers as (
  SELECT (SELECT value FROM ....) AS NUM_1,
         (SELECT value FROM ....) AS NUM_2,
         (SELECT value FROM ....) AS NUM_3
  FROM DUAL;
) 
select num_1, 
       num_2, 
       num_3, 
       num_1 + num_2 + num_3 as total
from numbers;
```

You have to make sure that your `(SELECT value FROM ....)` queries return **exactly** one row otherwise you'll get an error like "Single row sub-query returns multiple rows".

Answer (score -1):

Remove semi colon (;) after dual and then run as whole it will work

with numbers as (
  SELECT (SELECT value FROM ....) AS NUM_1,
         (SELECT value FROM ....) AS NUM_2,
         (SELECT value FROM ....) AS NUM_3
  FROM DUAL
) 
select num_1, 
       num_2, 
       num_3, 
       num_1 + num_2 + num_3 as total
from numbers;